# Not allowed document.write after page load?

Tags: javascript

I've been told that you can't use document.write after a page load, is this true?

I've created an extremely simple Javascript file that gets included from websites which serves as an advertising script. It just includes a `document.write('Link Here')`. I've been told that I should not do this though as apparently it isn't correct, and it will stop the page from loading?

Is this true? It works fine for me.

Thanks

Comment: It does not prevent the page from loading. However if the script is called after the document is closed (parsed), it will overwrite the content of the whole page.

Comment: @Felix Kling what is the correct method that I should use? document.writeln perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just write to the document itself it'll remove the page content and you'll be left with only the new text.

Try using:

```
document.getElementById('DIVID').innerHTML = "YOUR HTML HERE"
```

Substitute 'DIVID' for the element that will contain the ad and 'YOUR HTML HERE' for whatever you want to be written to the page). This will also allow you to position the ad on the page more easily.