# Understanding loops in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is my code, I'm not sure whether I am using the correct loop but this is basically want to do. I am trying get every src in the array to print out every one second, but the myPix[thisPic] becomes undefined when attempting to print out the second item in the myPix Array. I'd really be happy to get some help. Thank you!

```
function nextPic() {
    count = -1;
    thisPic = 0;

    if (thisPic == count) {
        document.write("This shouldn't ever happen");
        return false;
    } else {
        count++;
        var myPix = new Array("images/slideshow/Jellyfish.jpg", "images/slideshow/Penguins.jpg", "images/slideshow/Lighthouse.jpg");
        slideTag = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
        slideTag.src = myPix[thisPic];
        currPic = slideTag.src;
        document.write(myPix[thisPic] + "<br />");
        document.write(currPic);
    }

    return false;
}
setInterval(nextPic, 1000);
```

Comment: It really helps to format your code, so it can be read easily.

Comment: You don't seem to update `thisPic` anywhere and you are not using `count` anywhere except to compare it to `thisPic`, which will always be `false`. As such, `myPix[thisPic]` should never result in `undefined`. `myPix` is an array with at least one element. Did you omit something from your code?

Comment: Using `document.write` after the page has finished loading is [going to end badly at some point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985740/not-allowed-document-write-after-page-load).

Comment: do not use document.write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code doesn't work because "loop" has no shared variables. Every iteration should work on the same array and the same iterator, in Your code every iteration created new array and new iterator, so every iteration was doing the same thing.

To work correctly every loop iteration must:

1. Take current image src from array ( one variable declared outside loop )
2. Set it on img element
3. Change current variable to current+1 ( current variable delared outside loop )

If our current is more that array size then - end (**clearInterval**) or set current on 0 - then will start again and again ...

```js
//array declaration should be outside of loop

var myPix = new Array("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/50fbdd1dcbe4763a33a0e212f6a632c8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5be6299fb284071a9fd2cc2cc0b9090a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlB9c.jpg?s=48&g=1");

var currentPic=0; //this is number of current picture

function nextPic(){
          
        if (currentPic>= myPix.length){
          
          // here example how to stop:
          //clearInterval(interval);
          //return;
          
          //we loop it over again from begging
          currentPic=0;

        }
  
        //get img in page - image by currentPic
        slideTag = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1];//second
        //set src on this slideTag from array
        slideTag.src = myPix[currentPic];
  
        currentPic++;

        
}

var interval=setInterval (nextPic, 1000);//save interval in variable to use it to stop
```

```html
<h1>images</h1>
<img><br/>
<img><br/>
<img><br/>
```

> I taken example avatars from stackoverflow to show working example :)

Comment: Thank you so very much. I made the code more complicated than it needed to be in my head. I am really greatfull

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding your code, I have figurout your issue

```
    var myPix = ["images/slideshow/Jellyfish.jpg", "images/slideshow/Penguins.jpg", "images/slideshow/Lighthouse.jpg"];
    counter=0;
interval = setInterval (nextPic, 1000);
    function nextPic(){
        if(counter >= myPix.length){
            document.write("This shouldn't ever happen");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else{

            slideTag = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1];
            slideTag.src = myPix[counter];
            currPic = slideTag.src;
            document.write(myPix[thisPic] + "<br />");
            document.write(currPic);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```