# Page refreshes after setTimeout function and removes body attribute

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, document.write

The code below sets a timeout of 2s to call document.write function.
As soon as the `document.write()` is called, it automatically refreshes (as I thought) the page. Not only that, it removes bgcolor and color property of the body too!

```
// JS
let name = prompt('Enter username: ', 'Captain Anonymous');

function sayHello() {
    document.write('Hello ' + name + '!');
}
setTimeout(sayHello, 2000);

// HTML
<html>
<head><title>Page Title</title></head>
<body bgcolor='blue' color='white'></body>
</html>
```

I want that this code just simply writes the message in the document. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish? document.write after page load blows the page away. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985740/not-allowed-document-write-after-page-load

If you're attempting to make a page interactive, try setting the value of an element. If you're trying to generate messages, try console.log

Comment: This is what exactly document.write should do in your code

Comment: I wanted the code to just write into the document "Hello " + name + "!". WITHOUT refreshing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write only inserts text into your document while it's loading. Once the page is loaded, it will [overwrite your page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985740/not-allowed-document-write-after-page-load). When your setTimeout is called, the page is already loaded.

What you probably want to do is put a place in your page for your message.

Try this. Add a div tag inside the body of your page.

```
<div id="mytext">
```

Then change your sayHello function to this

```
function sayHello() {
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerText = 'Hello ' + name + '!';
}
```

Comment: Can we use innerText in place of innerHTML? Is it equally valid?

Comment: @Blue for your needs, yes. But, of course, it doesn't support HTML. e.g. `'<strong>Hello</strong>' + name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Kushner